# How to ensure seamless transition of hardwood flooring

Tags: flooring, hardwood-floor

I'm getting ready to install ~900 sqft of unfinished Brazilian walnut. The planks are 5" wide and 3/4" thick. Per the manufacturer guide, I plan on doing a 3/4" expansion gap on the perimeter and using baseboard plus quarter round to conceal it.

The lengths of my rooms run the same direction of my floor joists so I screwed down, with glue assist, a second layer of 15/32 plywood that staggered the joints of my first layer by at least a foot.

My question is, how do I ensure a seamless transition between the rooms? I want the flooring to be continuous and would like to not use transition pieces in the door ways. My concern is that I am almost certain my walls are not parallel and this will cause issues if I start in the right most room, snap a line on that exterior wall and start there.

Looking for advice on how to properly start the flooring and transition between rooms while keeping it all going the same direction with no transition pieces.

I've included a picture of the floor layout

[image]

---

Using the starting position as suggested in the reply. Its coming out nicely.

https://imgur.com/a/GkK4Pul

Comment: Believe it or not, you would start in the middle of the room

Comment: I would probably close to the centre and work out.  Measurements before are required to see how far out the walls are, but I would think less than an inch.

Comment: @Ruskes  That is good for one room, but OP is planning for the whole house as one floor room.  OP is much braver than I am.

Comment: @crip659 still the rule applies, and you are saying exactly the same

Comment: @ruskes you believe I should start in middle of hallway? Like the center point of the two exterior walls on long side?

Comment: Nope, for each of the large rooms find the center and start there, the hallway you can simply continue from the large rooms endings

Comment: I dunno...starting from the middle sounds like it'd require measurements that are very difficult to come by to ensure that your first board is "square."

Comment: With a square on the floor at the right angle, two chalk lines and three people. Then fight over making the line end up in the middle of the bath room doorway and the MB doorway.  Exterior walls are neither here nor there. Find the middle of the hallways, and stop when both people say it's off by the same amount. It's called *fudging it*.

Comment: Then dry fit some for several feet to see what it will look like. Then just give up and be closer to parallel with w/e the long run is, because that's the only place you can notice anyway. Dry fitting can get you back towards the wall (lay some down and make a new mark) instead on having to start in the middle and then work T&G backwards.

Comment: The first board *will not be square*. You leave that one out and put cutoffs later. And you put it so that you don't have to fill a 1/8" gap at one end and 1/2" gap at the other. That's a difficult piece to make. Leave room for like half the board width. Then dry fit or measure, that the other end of the room won't have the same problem. - Tile; you cut it in half and just go; provided the other end is about half a tile. - We joke about this at work all the time. It's called *Putting the X on the floor.* No one wants that responsibility.

Comment: If I wanted to _insure_ something, I'd call my insurance company, not a DIY forum :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you propose to do is done by pro floor layers all the time. Transition strips are not needed unless there is a difference in floor levels. If it is all the same level, and presumably it is a nail down floor, going from room to room is just a matter of careful planning.

The typical starting place is the longest run in the building. You have 2 places to choose from the MBR and closet, or the hallway and the bedroom. I would start in the MBR and closet. It has a run that is the longest.

Use the long wall of the bedroom to set 2 marks that will allow a chalk line pass through the closet door and continue the chalk line into the closet to the far outside wall. Take your pick on which way you want to start the floor and run it. I would start with the major part of the bedroom and go into the bathroom, if that is your plan. This will get most of the closet done too. To change direction, use a spline glued into the groove of the floor you just laid. This will provide a tongue to start the floor the other direction. Splines will be needed in other rooms too when you go through the door s with the first piece and will need to backfill behind the lead piece going into the various rooms.

Unless you really like shoe mold, you can under cut the drywall and use that as part of the 3/4" expansion space so the base will cover on its own. A reciprocating saw and a 1" rip of material 2 or 3 ft long acting as a guide can make fairly quick work of an otherwise miserable job. Only complication there, is perhaps the drywall nails that are in the bottom plate, if any.

Comment: My op is a bit bad. I forgot I moved the door for the closet in MBR to enter through the bathroom because I installed pocket doors in all rooms and closets but hallway closet. So the longest run is the hallway to bedroom. I updated the floor plans to address this

Comment: Yes that would be the case. Just a suggestion, if you do cut the drywall, or even if you don't, you could start the run 5" away from the wall if that line will get you around the door jamb, then you can backfill the  piece and face nail it, using a spline only at the other 2 bedroom doors.